# XML parsing using PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I have a table having 3 columns. 1st cloumn is id, second column is name,3rd column is XML document having 3 element.
I have to parse the XML using PIG and resulting table should contain 5 columns namely id, name and parsed elements from XML.
suggest me some solutions in PIG.

### input

1,abc,Guide1Computer144.95
2,bcd,Guide2Computer250.95

### Output should be

1,abc,Guide1,Computer1,44.95
2,bcd,Guide2,Computer2,50.95

Answer (score 0):

You should use XPath to flatten data within your 3rd column. Use a FOREACH-GENERATE and leave 1st and 2nd column as is and flatten the 3rd column using XPath.
This link might help you in the process: http://hadoopgeek.com/apache-pig-xml-parsing-xpath/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Following is the scenario   input 
-----
1,abc,<catalog><title>Guide1</title><genre>Computer1</genre><price>44.95</price></catalog>
2,bcd,<catalog><title>Guide2</title><genre>Computer2</genre><price>50.95</price></catalog>

Output should be
----------------
1,abc,Guide1,Computer1,44.95
2,bcd,Guide2,Computer2,50.95